# Alternative ways to store data base into a file

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks, dump

**What can I use instead of mysqldump to extract information from db to any file?**

I need to give back my computer and save information from it. Buy when I tried to save data base I had I faced a problem:

```
$mysqldump5 x -u root > x.150124.sql
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)
```

In internet people face such a problem because they have new mysql and old mysql dump. And they recommend to install mysql56. My versions looks similar:

```
 $ mysqldump5 --version
   mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.1.66, for apple-darwin11.4.2 (i386)
 $ mysql5 --version
   mysql5  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for apple-darwin11.4.2 (i386) using readline 6.2
```

but nevertheless I tried to install mysql56 using MacPorts (similarly to my previous mysql installation) and failed to do it because of errors py27-setuptools stage. All this problems looks quite complicated to solve and it is not guarantied that new problems wouldn't appear and I need the result quickly.

So I ask if there any other ways to store DB information. I don't really care about "clean solutions" and state of the system afterwards, since it will be reinstalled in any-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select ... into ... outfile
```

here is more info on it...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

edit:  even better link http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Data-Back-Up/Export-Data/How-to-use-SELECT-INTO-OUTFILE-statement-to-export-data

Comment: It is an option, thank you. But there are like 30 tables in my data base.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way, which I found is to stop current server:

> mysqladmin5 shutdown

and install mysql5.6.22 from dmg package (mysql community server for osx10.9), avoiding mac ports.
After that

> /usr/local/mysql-5.6.22-osx10.8-x86_64/bin/mysqldump -u root x > ~/x.150125.sql

did the job.

P.S. I don't accept this answer because it doesn't provide alternative solution for dumping. Therefore I accepted @Jose Martinez despite I didn't used that solution.